# Assistance converting vb.net code to c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I haven't used vb.net in years and need to convert some code to c#. So far it's going ok, but I came across the following code that has me stumped on how to convert it to c#.

```
Dim UnsavedLogEntries As StringBuilder
UnsavedLogEntries = context.Cache.Item(ObjNameInCache)
UnsavedLogEntries (vbCrLf + LogEntryTimeStamp + UserID + LogEntry)
```

Comment: Try `Telerik.com` converter

Comment: You have a lot of online converters... [Try this](http://www.laissemoichercherca.com/?q=convert%20vb.net%20to%20c%23)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [How To Ask?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and take the [Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to get an overview of this site and to avoid downvotes.

Comment: For vbCrLf you probably want "\r\n" or Environment.NewLine, and not the reference to the Microsoft.VisualBasic assembly that telerik suggests.

Comment: The vb code is not valid... e..g. Dim UnsavedLogEntries As StringBuilder should be Dim UnsavedLogEntries As New StringBuilder

Comment: @Mych: The stringbuilder is being assigned to on the next line, so that line *is* valid.  The last line is strange though.

Comment: Have to downvote this because that last line cannot possibly be valid.

Comment: Sorry about that regarding the last line. It should actually be: UnsavedLogEntries.Append(vbCrLf + LogEntryTimeStamp + UserID + LogEntry)

Comment: @NightHawk198889 - thanks for the update. In case you have to correct your question you should use the edit link and make the correction instead of posting the edit in your comment. That way users visiting your question for the first time will see the correct question immediately without having to also read the comments. Also if there is an answer that you deem as `the best one` for your question please mark it so using the checkbox next to the answer.

Comment: @Igor thanks will do that next time.

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim UnsavedLogEntries As StringBuilder
UnsavedLogEntries = context.Cache.Item(ObjNameInCache)
UnsavedLogEntries.Append(vbCrLf + LogEntryTimeStamp + UserID + LogEntry)
```

in c# this is the closest equivalent

```
System.Text.StringBuilder UnsavedLogEntries;
UnsavedLogEntries = (System.Text.StringBuilder) context.Cache.Item[ObjNameInCache]; // ObjNameInCache is some string variable somewhere in your code
UnsavedLogEntries.Append(System.Environment.NewLine + LogEntryTimeStamp + UserID + LogEntry);
```

---

> from the comments: ... regarding the last line. It should actually be: `UnsavedLogEntries.Append`...

Comment: VB has quirky indexer syntax. `context.Cache.Item(ObjNameInCache)` should most likely be `context.Cache[ObjNameInCache]`

Comment: Not sure how you figured that the last line was intended to be an Append since it was not indicated in the original (strange) last line.

Comment: @Igor, 3rd line of code in the original question is, indeed, peculiar. I'm unable to wrap my head around it.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas - I made an assumption. I have added an explanation on that assumption in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

[Telerik](http://converter.telerik.com/), [Tangible](http://www.tangiblesoftwaresolutions.com/Product_Details/Instant_CSharp.html), Varycode - there are a number of online and downloadable converters.

I tossed this into Instant C#, which I've used for large code conversions with good accuracy, and this is what it returned:

```
    StringBuilder UnsavedLogEntries = null;
    UnsavedLogEntries = context.Cache.Item(ObjNameInCache);
    UnsavedLogEntries[Environment.NewLine + LogEntryTimeStamp + UserID + LogEntry];
```

There are a number of online cheatsheets you can use for conversion help as well.

Good luck with your conversion.

Comment: @Igor: Yes, but neither does the original 3rd line compile (garbage in garbage out).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out. It would translate to the following in C#:

```
StringBuilder unsavedLogEntries;
unsavedLogEntries = (StringBuilder)context.Cache[ObjNameInCache];
unsavedLogEntries.Append(Environment.NewLine + logEntryTimeStamp + userId + logEntry);
```

A couple of things also. C# does not have an Item method on Cache. Also I needed to cast it to a StringBuilder to resolve not being able to convert from obj to StringBuilder.